# I want info about Silverlight controls using UI automation

Tags: c#-4.0

I want information like class name, control name, etc. for Silverlight applications. I have to write an application similar to silver light spy.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Use short and clear sentences. I can't understand anything of it...

Comment: hi Rhapsody ...i wanted to develop an application which gives information of silver light controls , similar to silver light spy

Comment: And what do you expect from the StackOverflow community? :) Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes i tried,i want some information for getting silver light control when i point mouse over it